# msgraph messages same ids

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft msgraph api to sync messages from my office365 mailbox to my application.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the ids of the messages are not unique. I have messages in my mailbox that are in the same folder and have the same exact id.

I verified the response of the requests I was sending in the graph explorer. I receive totally different messages with the same ids.

Could this be a bug in the msgraph api ? Or are message ids not unique ?

I'm talking to the following endpoint:

```
/me/mailFolders/[id_of_folder]/messages/delta
```

I'm using the php sdk provided by Microsoft but since the double ids are also visible in the graph explorer is doesn't seem to be a bug in the SDK.

Comment: Ids are case sensitive so beware

Comment: That was the problem. I was using mysql queries and they are case insensitive by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ids returned by Microsoft Graph, specifically, for Exchange Online Workload are case sensitive. Please compare with case sensitive comparators.